# Obtendo factory null em spring SessionFactory com Resource configurado

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

O nome da classe que contém o `SessionFactory` é `DataProvider` e possui a seguinte implementação:

```
@Resource(name="sessionFactory")
protected SessionFactory factory;

protected Class<E> entity;
protected String tableName;

public DataProvider(Class e) {
   this.entity = e;
   this.tableName = entity.getAnnotation(Table.class).name();
}

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<E> getAll() {
    Session s = factory.getCurrentSession(); // A exceção acontece aqui.
    return s.createQuery("FROM " + tableName ).list();
}
```

O bean com a configuração do `SessionFactory` é:

```xml
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="models"/>
    <property name="configurationClass" value="org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Estou obtendo `NullPointerException` na linha comentada. A pergunta é: estou fazendo algo de errado ou ainda falta alguma configuração?

Comment: Esse XML é o `persistence.xml` ou é outro?

Comment: A classe onde está esse código é um Bean gerenciado pelo Spring?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez O XML é do Spring.

Comment: Você pode atualizar a sua resposta para ter o `persistence.xml` + o código completo do Bean + a parte do XML que configura as injections do Bean?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez é o `applicationContext.xml`

Comment: E o pacote onde estão suas classes é só `models` mesmo?

Comment: @MiguelCartagena Sim!

Comment: Qual a versão do Spring que você está utilizando?

Answer (score 2):

Para o Spring resolver as dependências utilizando as annotations, é necessário adicionar uma configuração extra no seu applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

 <context:annotation-config/>

<context:component-scan base-package="br.com.meupacote." />

<!-- seus outros beans -->


</beans>
```

A configuração `<context:annotation-config/>` diz para o Spring que ele deve resolver dependências indicadas pelas annotations (qualquer uma das @Resouce, @Autowired ou @Inject), a configuração `<context:component-scan base-package="br.com.meupacote" />` diz para o Spring procurar por essas dependências  nas classes que pertecem ao pacote `br.com.meupacote.*` .

Além disso, para o Spring resolver as dependências na sua classe `DataProvider` essa classe deve pertencer ao contexto do Spring. Uma forma fácil de configurar isso é anotá-la com @Component. Exemplo:

```
@Component
public class DataProvider{
 // ....
}
```

Documentação da versão 3.0.0: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s11.html